# Connecting to OpenVPN config using python

Tags: python, openvpn

Is there any libraries for python that can be use for connecting to OpenVPN service using .ovpn configuration file?

The openvpn-api library needs OpenVPN installed on your system.

Comment: you can just start the OpenVPN service from your python program using Windows/Linux commands

Answer (score 1):

Good news - you don't need any external libs to connect openvpn.
You may just run cmd command from python script like this:

```
# write the command to a variable
cmd = 'start /b cmd /c "C:\Program Files\OpenVPN\bin\openvpn-gui.exe" --connect config.ovpn'
# split the command to parameters (It's not a necessity, it's just a rule of good taste)
args = shlex.split(cmd)
# run and remember the process as 'x'
x = subprocess.Popen(args, shell=True)
```